# Access div using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Anobody suggest me how to access DIV in td

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="95%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:25%">
            <img src="../NewsImages/82010437713162453512.bmp" id="rptAllNewsContent__ctl1_imgNews" width="120" height="120" />
        </td>
        <td valign="top" align="left" style="width:*;padding-left:7px;">
            dsdsdsd
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="width:20%;"><a id="rptAllNewsContent__ctl1_lnkbtnTotalComments" href="javascript:__doPostBack('rptAllNewsContent$_ctl1$lnkbtnTotalComments','')" style="color:#80C355;">2 Comments</a></td>
                    <td align="left"><a id="rptAllNewsContent__ctl1_lnkbtnAddComments" href="javascript:__doPostBack('rptAllNewsContent$_ctl1$lnkbtnAddComments','')" style="color:#80C355;">Add Comments</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="height:13px;"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="rptAllNewsContent__ctl1_divComment">
            sdfasdasda
            sdsa
            d
            asdas
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width:25%">
            <img src="../NewsImages/8201010976151655912.jpg" id="rptAllNewsContent__ctl2_imgNews" width="120" height="120" />
        </td>
        <td valign="top" align="left" style="width:*;padding-left:7px;">
            dasdasd
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="width:20%;"><a id="rptAllNewsContent__ctl2_lnkbtnTotalComments" href="javascript:__doPostBack('rptAllNewsContent$_ctl2$lnkbtnTotalComments','')" style="color:#80C355;">3 Comments</a></td>
                        <td align="left"><a id="rptAllNewsContent__ctl2_lnkbtnAddComments" href="javascript:__doPostBack('rptAllNewsContent$_ctl2$lnkbtnAddComments','')" style="color:#80C355;">Add Comments</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" style="height:13px;"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="rptAllNewsContent__ctl2_divComment">
                sdfasdasda
                sdsa
                d
                asdas
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried in this way but doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[id$='lnkbtnTotalComments']").click(function(){
        $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").next("tr").next("tr td").find("div").text();
        return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: Would you like to do your operation to every div, to every div in the table, to every div in particular rows or to some specific div?

Comment: to every div in particular rows.What i want is when i click on "...lnkbtnTotalComments" linkbutton the div in next row should slide down and if i click again it should slide up.

Comment: which version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: update your version to latest versioni.e.1.4.2....because the answers given below are using some enhanced property...try to do this. may be that works for you and let us know it helped you or not?

Comment: Can't we do something like $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").next("tr").next("tr td").find("div").Is there something missing.

Comment: try this...$(this).next("div").text()

Comment: In this way it return empty string value but div contain text = "sdfasdasda
            sdsa
            d
            asdas"

Comment: make sure that you don't have another div in between anchor tag and your desired div

Comment: Yeah!I am going in the same way as the rendered html i posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(completely different from my first solution)

Try this:
- get the id of the link clicked on
- replace "lnkbtnTotalComments" with "divComment" so we get the id of the matching div

```
$("a[id$='lnkbtnTotalComments']").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("lnkbtnTotalComments", "divComment");
    $("#" + id).html("gotcha");
    return false;
});
```

Works for me. You can do anything you want instead of changing the html contents of course.

Comment: following error comes: "Object doesn't support this property or method."

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[id$='lnkbtnTotalComments']").click(function(){
        $("#rptAllNewsContent__ctl1_divComment").text();
        return false;
    });
    });
```

Comment: I can't access it by id bcoz the html i have shown in question is rendered html of repeater.

Answer (score 0):

try: `$('#rptAllNewsContent__ctl1_divComment').text();`

Comment: I can't access it by id bcoz the html i have shown in question is rendered html of repeater.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalCommentsSel = "a[id$='lnkbtnTotalComments']",
        commentsContSel = "div[id$='divComment']",
        wrapper = "table";

    $(totalComments).click(function(e){
        var commentsDiv = $(this).closest(wrapper).find(commentsContSel);
        // Use commentsDiv below

        // Prevent the click from redirecting, but allow further propagation
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

EDIT:
This one does work (tested), but it's not pretty code. Any way you could change into a nicer markup?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalCommentsSel = "a[id$='lnkbtnTotalComments']",
        commentsContSel = "div[id$='divComment']";

        $(totalCommentsSel).click(function(e){
            var $wrapper = $(this).closest('table').closest('tr').next().next(),
                commentsDiv = $wrapper.find(commentsContSel);
                // Use commentsDiv below

                console.info($wrapper.length, commentsDiv.length, commentsDiv.length);
                // Prevent the click from redirecting, but allow further propagation
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Its giving error "Object doesn't support this property or method."